# How Can I Secure Outdoor Lightstrip on Balcony Railing Without Screws?

Tags: lighting, railing, balcony

I'm in a bit of a dilemma and could use some creative suggestions. I recently got an outdoor Hue lightstrip, and I want to install it on my balcony railing. The issue is that the railing is an upside-down L-shaped and I can't use screws or anchors to secure it because I don't want to cause any damage.

The bottom of the upside-down "L" on my balcony faces inward (towards the balcony), and the top of the "L" points towards the ground. I want to make sure the lightstrip stays securely in place without causing any damage.

Has anyone here faced a similar situation or has any out-of-the-box ideas for mounting the lightstrip without drilling? I'm open to DIY solutions, adhesives, clips, or any other ingenious methods you might have in mind. Given the shape of the railing, zip ties wont do the trick.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Clean the bottom very well.  Dabs of silicon caulking with clothes pegs to hold the strip on each side of the dabs, till it sets.

Comment: If you add something between the L and the strip, then you can probably get the zip ties to work. You should make a drawing. Doesn't have to be fancy. Sketch something, snap a picture with your phone, and upload it.

Comment: What's the railing made of? Do magnets stick to it? They do stick to some stainless steels, but not others, and obviously not aluminium.

Comment: Important question - if it falls out, will it kill anyone or risk damage? How 'serious; your attachment methods need to be is going to depend on that. A photo of the railing might be helpful too

Comment: Which part of the L do you want the strip to be on? Top, bottom, inside, outside?

Comment: I would use a small $2 wood  clamp (C, linear, or spring) to get a good grip on the board, and hang the string off the clamp.

Answer (score 3):

Automotive trim tape. It holds the letters and logos on your car in all weathers and temperatures. And at considerable wind speeds.

As usual with anything tape...

[image: trim tape]

*Image source http://multimedia.3m.com/mws/media/1141254P/3mtm-super-strength-molding-tape-03609-1-2-in-x-5-ft.jpg (not affiliated, but after some decades of using 3M and other brands they do seem to maintain their reputation by backing it up with performance.)*

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the underside of the "L" rail is relatively smooth and that you will clean it properly, this seems like the perfect application for [heavy duty outdoor adhesive-backed Velcro](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09BNPHCZX).

You can save some money by cutting it lengthwise to 1/2" width.

Comment: Any particular reason for recommending Velcro instead of just double sided tape? Seems a bit overkill to me, but maybe I'm missing something...

Comment: @FreeMan, only reason is that I knew they make one for outdoor use. Not sure if any of the "mounting tape" varieties are ok for exterior...